# Mongo abstracting field from multi field column

Tags: mongodb

I would like to be able to count the number of dealerships per state. The trouble I am having is that I have City/State/Zip all in one column. So, I need a way to abstract only the state from this.

This is an example of one of my results.

```
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a22c8e562c2e489c5df710a"),
        "2016rank" : 22,
        "Dealershipgroupname" : "West-Herr Automotive Group Inc.",
        "Address" : "3552 Southwestern Blvd.",
        "City/State/Zip" : "Orchard Park, NY 14127",
        "Phone" : "(716) 926-7052",
        "Companywebsite" : "www.westherr.com",
        "Topexecutive" : "Scott Bieler",
        "Topexecutivetitle" : "president",
        "Totalnewretailunits" : "29,486",
        "Totalusedunits" : "20,525",
        "Totalfleetunits" : 302,
        "Totalwholesaleunits" : "23,694",
        "Total_units" : "74,007",
        "Total_number_of _dealerships" : 25,
        "Grouprevenuealldepartments*" : "$1,805,200,100",
        "2015rank" : 20
```

This is the aggregate group code I wrote, but I want it to only use State.

```
db.car.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:"$City/State/Zip", count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

So how would I abstract out only state from City/State/Zip and use it in my aggregate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
db.car.aggregate([
    { $project : { city_state : { $split: ["$City/State/Zip", " "] } } },
    { $unwind : "$city_state" },
    { $match : { city_state : /[A-Z]{2}/ } },
    { $group : {_id:{ "state" : "$city_state" }, count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```